# pod lib create deployment_target

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec, podfile

I created a CocoaPod library project for iOS via the `pod lib create` command.

The `podspec` file that gets created adds the deployment target as iOS 8 in it. I want it to be iOS 11. There is no option to set it at the beginning as far as I know.

If I change it manually and run `pod install` again, it creates a static framework instead of a dynamic one.

How do I set/change the deployment target to something other than the default value?

Answer (score 0):

As a library provider you don't control the version that your clients choose to build with.  However, you can specify a minimum allowed version:

`  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'

See https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#deployment_target

Comment: Thanks for the response. After setting the deployment target to 11, it there a way to like "regenerate" the Xcode project to make the pod take this new deployment target into effect? Or do I do it manually from the Xcode's [Deployment info](https://i.imgur.com/g71eBoa.png)? Because without changing it in Xcode, I can't add swift files to the Development Pods directory.